# How can I target dynamic name of movieclip which is a child of another one

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

I'm trying to control a movieclip which is located in another movieclip, the problem is that the child movieclip has a dynamic instance name, please take a look for this example:

```
var myvar = "2";

mc_1.mc_2.y = 0; // that's ok
```

but if I try:

```
mc_1.this["mc_"+myvar"].y = 0;
```

> Syntax error: expecting identifier before this."`

I try:

```
this["mc_1.mc_"+myvar"].y = 0;
```

> Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.

and when I try that:

```
MovieClip("mc_1.mc_"+myvar").y = 0;
```

> Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "mc_1.mc_2" to flash.display.MovieClip.

one more try:

```
mc_1.MovieClip("mc_"+myvar").y = 0;
```

> Error #1006: MovieClip is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do :

```
var myvar:String = '2';

mc_1['mc_' + myvar].y = 0;
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: I just removed "`.this`" very simple (but not logical hhhhhh)

Comment: (: Sure ... the quotes  was a typing error in the example her